# Can damped motion in a time-varying potential escape to infinity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

Let $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy the differential equation $$m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} = -\nabla_x f_t(x),$$ where each $f_t$ is a nonnegative function that blows up as $||x|| \rightarrow \infty$. Here $m$ and $c$ are nonnegative numbers.

Moreover, all the $f_t(x)$ blow up as $||x||_2 \rightarrow \infty$ "uniformly.'' I'm flexible about what this means, but here is one suitable definition: there exists a nonnegative function  $\phi(x)$ with $\phi(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ whenever $||x||_2 \rightarrow \infty$ such that $$f_t(x) \geq \phi(x) \mbox{ for all } t.$$

My question is: is it true that $x_t$ remains bounded? Or is it possible for $x_t$ to escape to infinity in this scenario?

Comment: might be more appropriate to MathSE.

Comment: If the potential gives rise to an oscillating movement and synchronously injects more energy that the damping takes (perhaps something of the form $f_t(x)=kx^2+\sin{\omega t}$), I could imagine $x_t$ diverging.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,t) = \frac12 k~(x - v t)^2$ and related functions would seem to fit the bill.